# How does GC work with IEnumerator and yield?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I understand that enumerators and the yield keyword can be used to help with async/staggered operations, as you can call `MoveNext()` to run the next block of code.

However, I don't really understand what that Enumerator object is. Where does the memory in use of the scope of the Enumerator go? If you don't `MoveNext()` an Enumerator all the way, does it get GC'd eventually?

Basically, I'm trying to keep my GC hits down, as I am potentially using a LOT of Enumerators and GC can be an issue inside Unity, especially due to the older version of Mono it uses.

I have tried to profile this but can't wrap my head around them still. I don't understand the scoping/referencing that happens with Enumerators. I also don't understand if Enumerators are created as Objects when you create one from a function that yields.

The following example shows my confusion better:

```
// Example enumerator
IEnumerator<bool> ExampleFunction()
{
    SomeClass heavyObject = new SomeClass();
    while(heavyObject.Process())
    {
        yield return true;
    }

    if(!heavyObject.Success)
    {
        yield return false;
    }

    // In this example, we'll never get here - what happens to the incomplete Enumerator
    // When does heavyObject get GC'd?
    heavyObject.DoSomeMoreStuff();
}

// example call - Where does this enumerator come from? 
// Is something creating it with the new keyword in the background?
IEnumerator<bool> enumerator = ExampleFunction();
while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    if(!enumerator.Current)
    {
        break;
    }
}

// if enumerator is never used after this, does it get destroyed when the scope ends, or is it GC'd at a later date?
```

Comment: The compiler rewrites your enumerator method and moves the code into a class with an unspeakable name.  This class implements a state machine where your local variables become fields of the class, allows MoveNext() to be re-entered without losing state.  The IEnumerator interface reference is actually a reference to an object of that class.  Everything winks out of existence when that reference is collected, eligible to be GC-ed as soon as your code leaves the foreach loop.

Comment: Example of what Hans said: http://goo.gl/fs4eNo

Comment: Okay, thanks. That does not do what I expected AT ALL.

Does that mean Enumerators are fairly heavy compared to traditional means? I'm trying to keep GC down but it seems like I'm going to create new garbage anytime I start a new Enumerator (and I have a LOT of enumerators).

Comment: Keeping collection pressure down while making heavy use of IEnumerable and IEnumerator is a tricky problem but there are ways to do it. You should ask a separate question on that which clearly describes your scenario. You should also study carefully how the .NET libraries implement the enumerator of List<T>; it was designed to minimize collection pressure. Also, if you don't understand how foreach does duck typing style pattern matching, read up on that as well.

Comment: Meh, no, these are *very* small objects and they only have a reference while the foreach loop is looping.  The only way they'll make it out of gen#0 is when the loop does a lot of allocating.  In which case the small object is far removed from the real issue.  Focus on the right problem, this isn't it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably should read an enumerator internals post. From the internals you can answer all these questions.

A crash course: Each iterator method execution returns a new enumerator object. Local variables become fields.

If nobody uses that enumerator object anymore it is eligible for collection. Also, all references that local variables were creating go away for GC purposes.

There are some edge cases for when exactly local variables stop being GC references. If your enumerators are fairly short lived this does not matter much.

The CLR does not know what an enumerator is. It's just a class generated by the C# compiler.

Pulling the link by xanatos into this answer since it's illustrative and he does not seem to post an answer: http://goo.gl/fs4eNo

Comment: Right, that explains a lot. I wasn't aware how much automagic it was doing when it came to Enumerators.

I have a lot of methods that return Enumerators and I have a lot of things calling/using them. This sounds like it could be a GC problem, as every Enumerator coming in to existence is going to need GCing. It will have to be something I profile.

Answer (score 3):

> // if enumerator is never used after this, does it get destroyed when
>   the scope ends

Correct

Eligibility for collecting is having no references. For GC's scoping there is nothing special with enumerators. Enumerators disposed/cleared in the same way when they go out of scope as any other type.

Comment: If an Enumerator was never reference anywhere but locally from within a function, does it get GC'd cheaply/instantly? I don't fully understand GC but I know that as it can't be reference anywhere but inside the function, it's fairly straight forward to detect that it can be cleaned up?

Answer (score 2):

The enumerator is managed the same way as every other managed instance - when it is out of scope. Thus if `MoveNext()` is never called the GC deletes (or better marks it for deletion) the enumerator when it is out of its scope. Iterating an enumerator does not happen in any parallel so both execution and garbage-collection run deterministically and sequentually when you´re done with it.

When inside an iterator-method the `yield-return`-stament is not ment to be the very last statement at all, it simply means that when `MoveNext()` is called the current result should be returned. However everything behind `yield return` runs after the call to `MoveNext` so also your call to `DoSomeMoreStuff`.

Your `heavyObject` however has the scope of the method, thus it lives as long as the iterator - where the iterator is the block inside your `while`-loop. This means that if your iterator does not even return any instance `heavyObject` will be immediately disposed, otherwise when iteration has been finished.